# postgres column contain stringfy json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Hello actually I have an issue in converting column that contains json stringfy values to seperate columns

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|      informations                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|"{\n\"date\":" 2019-10-05"\n,\"value\":\n15\n,\n}"    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|"{\n\"date\":" 2019-05-25"\n,\"value\":\n89\n,\n}"    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

and what I want:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|      date        |value|
+------------------+-----+
|   "2019-10-05"   |   15|
+------------------+-----+
|   "2019-05-25"   |   86|
+------------------+-----+
```

I used json_to_recordset but not working
Thank you

Comment: What is the datatype of column `informations`?

Comment: @GMB the column datatype : text

Comment: Very similar to this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123053/function-json-populate-record-text-does-not-exist

Comment: Please post the query with `json_to_recordset` that you tried and the error you were getting.